# how make aws build ignore my dev dependencies

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I have a standard (hello-world) package.json for my aws lambda app:

```
{
  "name": "hello_world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "hello world sample for NodeJS",
  "main": "app.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/tree/develop/samcli/local/init/templates/cookiecutter-aws-sam-hello-nodejs",
  "author": "SAM CLI",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha tests/unit/"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^8.2.1"
  }
}
```

However if I run `npm i`, it creates `node_modules` folder within this `hello-world` folder which is deployed to AWS lambda when I run `sam deploy`.

It is not needed because I keep all necessary dependencies in a separate layer. However if I delete them, then I can't test locally (`sam local start-api`) because the app raises an exception since it can't find the dependencies. What should I do to avoid `node_modules` to be deployed to AWS but still have a possibility to run it locally?

Answer (score 3):

As a quick fix you could run `npm prune --production` before you deploy and a `npm install` afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:

Before deploying, remove `node_modules` folder and run `npm install --only=prod` command which will install only `dependencies` and will ignore `devDependencies`. Then deploy your app.

Option 2:

Install `chai` and `mocha` globally on your local machine and remove them from `package.json` at all. This will allow you to use those modules during local development.

**I'd recommend** to use the first option, because you will not need to install every single dev dependency globally. I'd also recommend you to setup any CI/CD (e.g. AWS CodeBuild) for build/deployment of your project and stop doing that from your local machine - that way you will not need to clean node_modules every time and you will have convenient general development process.

Comment: is `sam` really this terrible that it can't exclude dev deps automatically?